# Removing trailing zero after decimal point in python

Tags: python, floating-point, floor

```
import math
math.floor(85.21)
```

returns `85.0`

I want to save the number as a file name and I don't want to see the zero! I would like the output to be `85`

Answer (score 3):

Then you should consider *casting* to `int` which does the same thing but without the trailing `.0` instead of `math.floor`:

```
>>> int(85.21)
85
```

> I want to save the number as a file name

Since OP will not be working with negative numbers, they could keep this, or use `int(math.floor(...))` that works also for negative numbers.

Comment: The difference is that if the number is negative, `floor()` and a cast to `int` produce different results. The cast truncates (rounds towards zero), while `floor()` rounds towards negative infinity.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yes, that's true, but OP may not be working with negative numbers: *I want to save the number as a file name*

Comment: I understood that as that he wanted to create a file and store the value in it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It was good to be pointed that out anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
import math
result=int(math.floor(85.21))
print(result)
```

Comment: You can just use int